SAS how do I merge two datasets with two different conditions
here I have two datasets with patient ID, Visit, Visit dates and Results, one should be used as "Main" dataset with correct information while the other one has some inconsistent between Visit and Visit dates. Therefore, I want to merge the second dataset to the "Main" dataset to correct the visit dates. Please note that one visit can have multiple visit dates.
I have two scenarios:
1.One visit has multiple visit dates, the second dataset only have one with correct information, so I want to add a new row with the missing visit dates but with empty result.
2.The visit has only one visit date but the second dataset has the wrong date, so I want to correct the date only.
A very simple example: the main dataset looks like:



Patient ID
Visit
Visit Date
Result1




A
visit1
2024-9-11
1


A
visit1
2024-9-12
2


B
visit1
2024-9-13
3



The second dataset looks like:



Patient ID
Visit
Visit Date
Result2




A
visit1
2024-9-11
123


B
visit1
2024-9-11
456



And the dataset I want:



Patient ID
Visit
Visit Date
Result1
Result2




A
visit1
2024-9-11
1
123


A
visit1
2024-9-12
2
.


B
visit1
2024-9-13
3
456



Here patient A and B represent the scenarios 1 and 2. Hope someone could help to figure out a simple SAS code to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

And what do you do with RESULT2 values for patient/visits that span multiple dates but the date in the RESULT2 file is not in the RESULT1 file?  Do you "insert" an observation and have RESULT1 as missing?

From your description, we can trust the date in Dataset 2 if there are multiple dates in Dataset 1, but we cannot trust the date in Dataset 2 if there is only one date in Dataset 1. The only way around this problem I see is to consider two separate lookups using the two scenarios:

If there are multiple visits, lookup by patient_id, visit, visit_date
If there there is only one visit, lookup by patient_id, visit

Both of these should yield unique lookups for each scenario. If you create a new variable, n_visits, to count the number of visits for each patient, you can do a dual lookup using hash tables in a DATA Step to account for each scenario.
proc sql;
    create table dataset1_counts as
        select *, count(*) as n_visits
        from dataset1
        group by patient_id, visit;
quit;

data want;
    set dataset1_counts;

    if(_N_ = 1) then do;

       /* Scenario 1: Multiple visit dates */
       dcl hash h1(dataset:'dataset2');
            h1.defineKey('patient_id', 'visit', 'visit_date');
            h1.defineData('result2');
       h1.defineDone();

       /* Scenario 2: One visit date */
       dcl hash h2(dataset:'dataset2');
            h2.defineKey('patient_id', 'visit');
            h2.defineData('result2');
       h2.defineDone();

       call missing(result2);
    end;

    /* Use the first lookup for multiple visits. Otherwise, use the second. */
    if(n_visits > 1) then rc = h1.Find();
        else rc = h2.Find();

    drop n_visits rc;
run;

patient_id  visit   visit_date  result1 result2
A           visit1  2024-09-11  1       123
A           visit1  2024-09-12  2       .
B           visit1  2024-09-13  3       456

